# How I can create a raster and have the same overlay as another raster in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay

I have made a graphical model in QGIS 2.4. I have to create a raster equation to rasterize a polygon shapefile. I want to rasterize my shapefile and I want to ensure that this new raster will perfectly overlay the position of another raster. I have used the tool "Rasterize" but it does not overlap my other image.

In ArcGIS we have some parameters that allow to specify to snap the pixel raster to another but I can't find the equivalent in QGIS. Can somebody help me?